# Is there a quick way to build all targets in Qt Creator?

Tags: build, cmake, qt-creator, target

I have a large CMake project in Qt Creator with hundreds of targets. To build all of them at once (which is something I only need to do once in a while) the best way I know is to go to *Projects*, *Build*, *Build Steps*, and uncheck *Current executable* in the *Targets* list.

Then I usually forget to change it back and wonder why my next compilation takes an hour.

Is there a better way to trigger an occasional building of all targets?

Comment: It seems that question is specific for QT Creator; don't you think it should be noted in the question post and in its title?

Comment: @Tsyvarev question body absolutely, title not sure, there are conflicting opinions here on whether to replicate tags in the title

Comment: Hmm, as far as I understand those "conflicting opinions", they are about those tags, which are added to the title **automatically** (or otherwise denote the programming language). Unfortunately, `qt-qreator` doesn't belong to such tags. And without it the title looks... controversially: My first interpretation of the title was "how to build all targets in CMake *in general*". Also, there is no "conflicting options" in that a nice title is a good title. And "Is there a quick way to build all targets **in QT Creator**?" seems to be a nice title for me. In any case it is up to you to decide.